# R.Studio: Lost my code changes while zooming out using "ctrl" + "-" in Rstudio source editor

Tags: r, editor, rstudio

I was using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to make the code font smaller (or zooming out) in the R studio source editor and I got the pop up window (picture attached).

I think I pressed OK by mistake and I lost a huge chunk of code. How can I recover that?

Also. it makes me bit skeptical of using Rstudio. [Pop out message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhJQL.png)

Comment: There is no shortcut for zooming out. If you want to make the code font smaller, go to Tools -> Global Options and in the Appearance Tab change the font size to whatever value you prefer.

Comment: Hi, actually if you press <kbd> Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd> -</kbd>/<kbd> +</kbd>, it does zoom in and out. But if you press it multiple times, it shows a pop out message as I shown in the picture. It makes me nervous now to use Rstudio. I don't know why my <kbd> tags are not working

Comment: All shortcuts in R Studio can be found here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts As you'll see, there is no default shortcut for zooming in/out. You can however customize a shortcut for this, as per here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> is the undo command (Windows)

For other shortcuts:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts

From a beginner standpoint, I find rstudio to be one of the most user friendly dedicated IDE's available for any programming language.

Comment: ctrl+z is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Any idea about the message in pop out window? and is my code recoverable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, a JSON file with your code is available at

> C:\Users[your user]\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\sources

Follow instructions as:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51433764/3142205

This is a terrible bug that RStudio has. I have never seen a code editor that every time you change the zoom level you lose your code! It is a terrible issue that makes me wonder if I should go back to Notepad++. I have never lost a file using Notepad++.

**Updated**: This issue has been solved in RStudio 1.2.1335 "Allow changing zoom level without reloading (#2125)".

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>+</kbd> on the right keyboard, don't use key.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I immediately press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>. If this is not recovering your code try with history tab -> go to history tab:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

may the shortcut of `Zoom Source Editor`    with `Ctrl+Shift+1` is a substitute plan.
It’s a pity that Rstudio doesn't provides a support to `ctrl + +/-(mouse scroll)`