# how to recovery unsaved R codes?

Tags: r, history

Please please help me. I was working on a project I saved my file to my desktop . yesterday after closing I pushed unsaved by mistake. I opened R today and it shows me the code that I had saved before.all my new codes disappeared I worked very hard in 4 last days and made some changes, is there a way to recovery my unsaved codes?

Comment: Can you add more background please: Which editor and OS are you using, which file system...

Comment: could you please tell me how I can get this information?

Comment: I am using RStudio

Answer (score 1):

Try `history(Inf)` to get command history, even from previous sessions.

Comment: it does not give me whole of my previous code. it was 1500 line code

Comment: is there any file that I can find?

Comment: check out @Iman answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223435/how-to-get-unsaved-script-tabs I think this can be useful in your case.

Comment: actually your solution gives me half of my work. is it possible to get whole?

Comment: I don't use windows I have mac

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way. Go to My Computer -> Documents -> and there you should see your unsaved .R scripts

Comment: could you please explain more? I have mac

Comment: I use windows, but the basic idea is that your closed .R tabs are not automatically deleted from your machine, rather can be accessed from the documents folder. Try to find the MAC alternative of My Computer -> Documents folder in your system. Also, if you remember the name of your closed tab, try to search in your machine for that, e.g. vectors.R