# Recovery unsaved R.script in R

Tags: r, rstudio

Recently I closed an R.scrip and DONT save the changes (i.e. I lost almost all my work...).
I would like to know if there is some option to recovery back My previous version of that scrip

- This script is not associated with any R.project
  [how to recovery unsaved R codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123871/how-to-recovery-unsaved-r-codes)

I found this similar question, but since my scarce knowledge in R I am not able to replicate. Could someone explain me with all possible details how (if is possible) recover my previous R.scrip.
I looked in the R folder but did not found nothing. Also * tried in "Documents* but same result (nothing).
I really appreciatte the help

Comment: You could look through your RData file (back up if you use RStudio) or the History tab. Neither option will be clean or easy. You will have to piece together the script. However, if you executed the script file all at once, it may not be that bad. In the History pane, you can search for something that may be somewhat unique to that script file and start from there.

Comment: So you had never saved the file before? And when you closed the file, you confirmed in the dialog box that you didn't want to save it? If you confirmed that you don't want to save, then the changes are lost. There's no backup after the confirmation.

Comment: @Kat thanks for the suggestion, this solved an issue that I have had with a missing RMD file!!!