# How do I recover an R script?

Tags: r, rstudio

I was running an R script code in Rstudio and suddenly my computer power had been lost. Now, I open the script and I can't find anything in my script except red dots (see the below figure).

[image: figure]

I know that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223435/how-to-get-unsaved-script-tabs/45638229). However, the answers don't work for me. How can I recover my running code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file in my directory `C:\Users\Mohammad Nabati\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop` named `history_database.1` that I found the history of running.