# Is there a way to autosave my work in R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

R studio desktop froze up, and I lost everything. I've checked the Environment/History panel, and I'm not showing the project instead, I'm showing older projects. Is there a way to autosave my work on the R studio desktop to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: first i would open up the .rproj file again--if rstudio crashed and you open it again, you may have a blank workspace but your unsaved changes are actually under the project directory. second if i ever close or crash, i always have even my unsaved scripts pop up again when i re-open as i mentioned. third are you just talking scripts? i do not like to save objects/workspace in rstudio, that forces you to be reproducible and mobile. in fact, i regularly restart and clean the workspace. finally it sounds like you are asking if objects/workspace will be saved automatically on crash, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

RStudio *does* back up your changes. It should bring them up by itself if you re-open your project, but see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223435/how-to-get-unsaved-script-tabs) where you can find them directly.

Moreover, you can customize this behavior under Tools/Global Options/Code/Saving:

[image: RStudio options dialog]

Perhaps the right choice for you is not just backup, but actually save "when editor loses focus".

Lastly, it is highly recommended to use some source control - this won't just avoid losing your work, it would enable accessing all past versions of it.