# R code and all backups are empty all of a sudden

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been working on an R file in RStudio for months. I saved the file last friday, and when opening it again on monday, the file was completely empty (size 0kb). When retrieving previous versions of the file, I can see that the file has been saved multiple times during the previous week, but somehow all of these previous versions of the file are empty as well.

I make daily backups, but somehow the file in the backup is empty aswell for the last 2 months. The most recent backup in which the file still has coding it in, is from july 1st.

Does anyone know how i could retrieve the coding?

Thanks!

Comment: Something similar happened to me with certain version of RStudio, try to open the files using a text editor like Notepad++ and the codes should be there, if you open the same file on RStudio the codes are gone when saved. What is the version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: Using other editors unfortunately doesn't help either. The file remains empty.

Comment: I'm using R version 4.2.3 and RStudio version 2023.06. Mountain Hydrangea. Unfortunately, I am working in a secure remote access environment, so I cannot work with other versions.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223435/how-to-get-unsaved-script-tabs/) helps. On the long run I'd recommend using a version control system like git (supported for RStudio projects).

Comment: If the files are showing up as having 0 bytes, then the content is gone.  You say you are in a "secure remote access environment"; maybe the administrator of that environment has independent backups.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is almost certainly an OS fault, not related to R or other programming language.